# Should I use Spring Cloud Gateway or Ngnix for Web application

Tags: angular, spring, nginx, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I create a full application microservice architecture based on the Spring Cloud Gateway as Api Gateway, with backend services, RabbitMQ, etc. as shown in link to the screenshot below, suggested by Spring. I also have a web application written in Angular and SSO in the form of Keycloak. I base my web application on Nginx.

https://spring.io/images/diagram-microservices-dark-4a2e5817aac093437f4f3b3a5be8be88.svg

My question is whether **the main entry** point should be Spring Cloud Gateway, followed by routing to a web application, or rather Nginx Angular, which makes queries to Api Gateway and SSO as a separate entity?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: If you are using Keycloak's UI for auth, you could go either way but if you rely on Keycloak's APIs, my suggestion would be to make Spring Cloud gateway the entry point of backend services only. The users hit the Nginx Angular first and for backend APIs, they are routed by SCG.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I used to using SCG as a resource server which used Keycloak API but currently I'm thinking about less hitting the Gateway to limit requests produced by services. So I'm trying to invoke SSO directly from frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I think we could learn a lot about Spring Cloud Gateway from Netflix Zuul because it's originated(?) from Zuul.

In Zuul cases, the main entry point is the gateway.

Zuul articles and slides:
https://github.com/Netflix/zuul

Zuul vs Nginx performance comparision:
https://instea.sk/2015/04/netflix-zuul-vs-nginx-performance/

Comment: First of all Zuul is in the maitenance mode. Currently is the era of reactive programming, Zuul uses Tomcat which has blocking threads, real comparision is below:
[link](https://medium.com/@the.raj.saxena/springboot-2-performance-servlet-stack-vs-webflux-reactive-stack-528ad5e9dadc)
I can recommend you think in reactive way while building efficient solutions.